# oracle sql no data found after call function

Tags: sql, function, select, dml

I have task to implemented function.
I create function get_month to get the month in `string` from date with date format is `'DD/MM/YYYY HH24:MM:SS'` , and this is the code.

```
create or replace FUNCTION GET_MONTH(tgl DATE) RETURN VARCHAR2
IS mnth VARCHAR2(20);
BEGIN
    mnth := TO_CHAR(to_date(tgl, 'DD/MM/YYYY HH24:MI:SS'), 'Month');
    RETURN UPPER(mnth);
END;​
```

I use query :

```
SELECT GET_MONTH('12/02/2018 04:12:12') FROM dual;
```

and its work resulting `FEBRUARY`

I have a table `A` with column `MNTH` and `COST`. the data in table `A` is all month from JANUARY until DECEMBER in UPPERCASE and the data in cost all is 0.

When I try to make query :

```
SELECT cost 
FROM A 
WHERE mnth = GET_MONTH('12/02/2017 12:12:12');
```

it say no rows selected, but when I using

```
SELECT cost FROM A WHERE mnth = 'FEBRUARY';
```

resulting 0. I dont know why the function not working. Any one who know why ?
Sorry for my english

Comment: Calling `to_date()` on a value that is already a `date` is senseless and wrong. It will first convert the `date` to a `varchar` just to convert it back to a `date` which it was to begin with. Your code should read `mnth := TO_CHAR(tgl, 'Month');` And you should _call_ that function with a proper date, not a `VARCHAR` value, e.g: `GET_MONTH( DATE '2018-02-12')`

Comment: OK thank you @a_horse_with_no_name , but still it say no rows selected after I change the select condition into `where mnth = get_month(DATE '12/01/2018 14:30:22')` or `where mnth = get_month(to_date('12/01/2018 14:30:22','DD/MM/YYYY HH24:MI:SS'))`